# How to get a texture that changing every frames on a game object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First of all, sorry for my English. 
I would like to backup some textures into a list from a game object that has different texture for every frame. I tried to do this and I pushed textures into the list every frames but all of pushed texture seems like overwritten to the latest texture... I also tried Instantiate(); when each textures are pushed into the list but the textures were completely transparent. I'm not using movie texture. Does anyone know how to make this??

I might didn't explain enough so please ask me if something is not clear.
Thank you

`//Those line of codes are looping every frame
//This is the current code
transitionTextures.Add(targetGameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().materials[0].mainTexture);`


`//This is the another code that I tried
transitionTextures.Add(Instantiate(targetGameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().materials[0].mainTexture));`

Answer (score 0):

```
**transitionTextures.Add(targetGameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().materials[0].mainTexture);**
```

This line of code copies the reference of targetGameObject.GetComponent().materials[0].mainTexture to the list so according to copy by reference rule when ever targetGameObject's mainTexture is changed it will change all references in the list to the updated new value. so you should create a new object so it should be copied by value like this

```
 Texture2D temp = targetGameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().materials[0].mainTexture as Texture2D;

 Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(temp.width, temp.height);
 tex.SetPixels(temp.GetPixels());
 tex.Apply();

 transitionTextures.Add(tex);
```

Try this , it might help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried this code and it has another problem actually... temp.GetPixels() returns error of "Texture '' no data". I spent few hours but no luck yet.. Do you know why is this happening?